# Eiffel redefined function can define its own assertions?

Tags: assertions, eiffel

I need to know if a redefined function in Eiffel can define its own assertions.

Comment: So you can't answer this question *after* having read about "design by contract"? Also it's unclear what "its own" assertions actually means. An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can. But a redefined feature can only **weaken** its parent's precondition and **strengthen** its postcondition. To make it clearer you are forced to declare your precondition as a `require else` in the redefined feature, and declare the postcondition as an `ensure then` to make it clear that you are weakening/strengthening the corresponding assertion.

See the [documentation site](http://docs.eiffel.com/book/method/et-inheritance#Inheritance_and_contracts) for a more in depth explanation.